# SML Interpretation

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, factor-models, asset-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory, factor-investing

I follow this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3350138) and estimated two different asset pricing models via systems of deep neural networks. Both models have the exact same input: firm-specific features for 10'000 (unique) US stocks and a large set of macroeconomic variables over 20 years (training period = 1970-1990), but differ slightly in architecture. More specific: I have estimated two different stochastic discount factors and consequently two different tangency portfolios $F_{t}$ that account for time-variation. From there on I have estimated via another neural network the risk loadings as output $y = R^e_{t,i}F_t$ to estimate $\beta_{t,i}=\mathbb{E}_t[R^e_{t,i}F_t]$ which is proportional to the true $\beta_{t,i}$.

Some out-of-sample differences in results for the period 1995-2019 (after ensembling over 10 runs):

- Sharpe Ratio of $F_t$ for model 1 is 2.8, model 2 only 0.9
- Total cumulative return for model 1 is about 8 (800%), for model two 14.
- Maximum drawdown for model 1 is 8% over the whole period, for model 2 it is 59%
- Monthly avarge turnover for model 1 is 0.6, for model 2 it is 0.07
- Model 2 loads more heavily on small- and micro-cap stocks, but does not, at no point in time, load up on short positions in stocks. Model 1 does and, so I assume, can achieve this higher Sharpe ratio.

In short, model 2 is more index-like with high exposure to the MKT factor, and as mentioned, to the SMB factor. Model 1 is nearly MKT and SMB neutral. Model 2 can be very well explained by FF5, whereas model 1 cannot:
[image]
To investigate the SML, I normalized all obtained $\beta_{t,i}$ cross-sectionally by making sure that $\beta_t^{F_t}=1$, since I do not estimate it directly and built equally-weighted $\beta$-decile portfolios for both models. Then, I did a plain-vanilla regression and obtained this:

[image]

Given no-arbitrage, the intercept should be at 0, since I operate in the excess-return space. Both models do a quite satisfying job. But I am still puzzled: model 1 indicates an equity risk premium of 4.65% p.a. which is, given all the results from research, a reasonable result. Model 2 has an even better fit, but indicates a whopping premium of 12.1% p.a.

My current interpretation is that model 2 indicates a higher premium since it loads more heavily on small-caps, which offer (on paper) a attractive risk-return profile.

**Q:** Do you have any suggestions, or interpretations on why both models obtain such a good fit but differ that much in slope for the exact same input data?

**EDIT 1 (in response to Chris' questions)**

- Holding period on your two strategies? **Monthly rebalancing for both models.**
- A Sharpe of 2.8 is quite high (like, top decile+) for a long-only buy
  and hold mid to low frequency equity strategy. Even .9 is on the high
  side for a broad-based US index. **Model 1 is not long-only, it also takes short positions in stocks. Model 2 is long-only. The original authors obtained also a similar SR of 2.65 for a slightly different period.**
- Using 70-90 as a training set and 95-present as an out of sample set seems prime for issues related to change in regime. I can't think of a cut-off (ie, 1995) more aligned with a general shift in underlying business models, specifically the emergence of tech as a primary driver in US equities. **I agree here, I didn't think of that. I choose 20 years of trianing in order to have a large set available for training but not a too large one, since training on this already takes 23 hours per ensemble (10 runs per ensemble). Then I took 5 years (1990-1995) for validation. And the rest is testing. This way I have a very long out-of-sample period which I deem to be important to test such models, especially to analyze their behavior during the dot-com bubble and GFC 2008. Moreover I want to compare my results to the original paper with similar periods.**
- Regarding your follow-up question, why are you 'investigating SML'?
  How are you normalizing your betas across assets? How are you
  constructing your subsequent portfolio(s)? You'll need to provide
  more detail. **I'm new to this area of empirical asset pricing research and, correct me if I'm wrong, as far as I understand is that classical models fail to capture equity risk premia correctly and that many models return flat SML which, compared to historical (positive) risk premia, is something like a paradox, right? So, besides nice Sharpe ratios, a model must be able to explain differences in returns via differences in risk exposures to the systematic factor $F_t$. Well, I follow this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3350138) and estimate via neural networks a portfolio weight $\omega_{t,i}$ for the implicit tangency portfolio $F_{t+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}\omega_{t,i}R_{t+1,i}$, where  $\omega_{t,i}$ is the output of the NN-system. The betas I estiamte not via linear-regression but with another NN and only as a proportion. This way, I (and the original authors) can avoid estimating a covariance matrix for thousands of stocks every month. This means, for every stock I get a approximate beta that should be proportional to its true beta. Since I get this for all stocks, I can compute the weighted average beta for $F_{t}$ given the weights above. This $\beta^F_{t}$ will not be 1, so I have to scale all single stock betas in that cross-section with 1/$\beta^F_t$, such that finally $\beta^F_t=1$. Then I sort stocks cross-sectionally into deciles based on their beta and weigh them equally in these portfolios. Every month, to be evaluated in the subsequent month. Finally, for the SML i compute the mean excess returns and mean betas for all these porftolios over the testing period and perform this regresion above.**

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to pick apart here, but to start:

(1)  Holding period on your two strategies?  A Sharpe of 2.8 is quite high (like, top decile+) for a long-only buy and hold mid to low frequency equity strategy.  Even .9 is on the high side for a broad-based US index.

(2)  Using 70-90 as a training set and 95-present as an out of sample set seems prime for issues related to change in regime.  I can't think of a cut-off (ie, 1995) more aligned with a general shift in underlying business models, specifically the emergence of tech as a primary driver in US equities.

(3)  Regarding your follow-up question, why are you 'investigating SML'?  How are you normalizing your betas across assets?  How are you constructing your subsequent portfolio(s)?  You'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I made an update. Hope it helps.